# How to override JRE native libraries?

Tags: java

Is it possible to override a JRE native library with a library in my own location? I tried using `-Djava.library.path=...`, but when I check `lsof -p`, the process is still using the JRE copy.

Background: In Oracle JRE 7 on Mac OS X, the `javax.security.smartcardio` library is broken. It segfaults if you call list() too often. But since the fix was simple (incorrect 64-bit function signature), I was able to build OpenJDK and produce a fixed `libj2pcsc.dylib` library, which I want to use without replacing the system library if possible.

Comment: I think easiest fix would be to backup the system library and rename yours to that.

Comment: Why don't you just use OpenJDK instead of Oracle JRE?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but one idea that comes to mind is the java [extension mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/). I've never tried it myself, but perhaps it can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can link your fix into a shared object then you can try to force it to be loaded before the system library by setting LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/libj2pcsc.dylib java com.yourpkg.YourClass
```